# Why does this led driver label acl and acn opposite?

Tags: led-driver

[image]

I purchased this led light and it has a driver. But the label for load and neutral are opposite of what I would expect. Note that it says ACL (line) white and ACN (neutral) black.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I guess they didn't have an UL guy or an engineer with North America standards review the design , ACL ought to be black. Does it have any safety labels?

Comment: AC Line and AC Neutral.  Attach Black to appropriate line voltage and white to appropriate neutral and do not ye neglect to connect the ground/bond wire.  Never mind if that were correct the colors would be reversed.  Is it an LED ballast of some sort?

Comment: If it is a line voltage AC load of some sort, I would trust the engineer to choose the right color more than I would trust the intern to correctly handle the labelling.

Comment: Ok, so ignore the label

Comment: L means line, not load.

Answer (score 2):

In reality, it shouldn't matter which conductor is tied to Line and Neutral.

There is a (slight) possibility that there may be only a single capacitor tied from one of the output leads to Neutral but that is rare - most have a single capacitor from output lead to (-) terminal of the incoming AC bridge rectifier.